# Какой подход написания использовать во vue 3 TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue3

Во vue 3 представили новый подход Composition API. Я знаком с option api из vue 2 и так же ознакомился с composition. Сегодня сгенерировал проект с помощью vue CLI на vue 3 + TypeScript. Мое удивление было когда я зашел в компонент Home (сгенерированный vue cli) и увидел что он написан на class-components. Вроде разработчики отказались от поддержки данного подхода, но vue cli из коробки поставляет class-components. ВОПРОС какой подход использовать в проекте vue 3 + TypeScript? Оставлять и писать компоненты в классовом стиле или переписывать существующие на defineComponent и таким же образом реализовывать нове компоненты?

P.S. Буду благодарен за ссылку на ресурс на котором можно следить за всеми такими изменениями во vue и vue ts